# Convert or Execute an CURL Request for Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

How can I execute the following request in my Ruby on Rails controllers?

```
curl -X POST \
 -F "id={object-url OR object-id}" \
 -F "scrape=true" \
 -F "access_token={your access token}" \
 "https://graph.facebook.com"
```

Comment: _“How to perform this post via API in my Rails application?”_ - same as you perform any other API calls …?

Comment: Still not a good question. Rule of thumb: Whenever you feel compelled to just drop a “how can I …” question, it most likely means that you should do more proper research at this point. You can ask us when you encounter a specific problem. But right now, you should go research/read up on how you make POST requests in your RoR environment, plus what the individual parameters of the cURL example mean, if you are unsure about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [rest-client gem](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client).You can make HTTP request from your controller using this.
Their github page has examples explaining how to make reuqest along with paramters.
A simple get request may look like this:

```
RestClient.get '"https://graph.facebook.com', {params: {'scrape'=> true, 'access_token' => 'your_access_token'}}
```