# Rails helper output API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have a helper method

```
def greet
    now = Time.now
    today = Date.today.to_time

    morning = today.beginning_of_day
    noon = today.noon
    evening = today.change( hour: 17 )
    night = today.change( hour: 20 )
    tomorrow = today.tomorrow

    if (morning..noon).cover? now
      'Good Morning'
    elsif (noon..evening).cover? now
      'Good Afternoon'
    elsif (evening..night).cover? now
      'Good Evening'
    elsif (night..tomorrow).cover? now
      'Good Evening'
    end
end
```

I would like to be able to fetch the output via an external GET request. Is there anyone who can help me figure out how that can be done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49451049/convert-or-execute-an-curl-request-for-rails-application/49453005#49453005

Comment: With this much information, i can't, but `Net::HTTP` can help: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you'll need a controller. You can create it on `app/controllers/greetings_controller.rb`

The content of this controller would be something like:

```
class GreetingsController < ApplicationController
    def greet
        now = Time.now
        today = Date.today.to_time

        morning = today.beginning_of_day
        noon = today.noon
        evening = today.change( hour: 17 )
        night = today.change( hour: 20 )
        tomorrow = today.tomorrow

        if (morning..noon).cover? now
            'Good Morning'
        elsif (noon..evening).cover? now
            'Good Afternoon'
        elsif (evening..night).cover? now
            'Good Evening'
        elsif (night..tomorrow).cover? now
            'Good Evening'
        end
    end
end
```

Now you have your controller set. The next thing you want to do is to attach a route to it. Open the `config/routes.rb` file.

Append this to the file:

```
get '/greet', to: 'greetings#greet'
```

The only thing you need to change is your `#greet` response. It should call the method `format.json { render json: "Content" }` for it to work.

Change it to:

```
if (morning..noon).cover? now
    format.json { render json: 'Good Morning' }
elsif (noon..evening).cover? now
    format.json { render json: 'Good Afternoon' }
elsif (evening..night).cover? now
    format.json { render json: 'Good Evening' }
elsif (night..tomorrow).cover? now
    format.json { render json: 'Good Evening' }
end
```

Run `rails server` in your terminal and open your browser. The route `/greet.json` should work.

Comment: That solved the problem, but the output is plain Good Morning. How can I serve it in JSON format?

Comment: `render json: { greeting: "Hey" }`